# how to perform tap/on Pressed action on Sliver list specific item in flutter integration test

Tags: flutter

Need to perform on pressed operation using automation testing in flutter integration testing.
There is Sliver List used in my app and on that Sliver list when user tap on Sliver list item it will call on Tap method which I implemented but now need to do the same in integration test. Is there any way to perform tap on Sliver list element.

```
SliverList(
childCount:10,
delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((context, index) {
return ListItem(log: _logs![index],onPress: () => onPressed(_logs![index]),);
});
)
```

Comment: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/testing/integration/introduction#4-write-the-integration-test

Answer (score 0):

Use the `tester.tap(widgetToTap)` method for any kind of pressing/tapping.

Comment: That does not work as it says tap only works with RenderBox objects

Comment: Would you mind sharing your code snippet here?